# Найти нужную страницу в Instant CMS

Tags: php, mysql, cms, instantcms

Достался сайт в котором необходимо произвести некоторые изменения, а конкретно необходимо отредактировать калькулятор. А я ни как не могу найти страничку для редактирования. Нашел только расположение javascript. Есть догадки что всё хранится в БД, но опять таки как где всё это вызывается? Сайт [развлечения для детей](http://skaz-gorod.ru/kalkuljator-tvoego-prazdnika.html).

Кто знаком с данной CMS подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что именно надо отредактировать в калькуляторе? Так то все прописано в calc.jsЦенник и прочее в скрипте calc.js, оформление в файле формы. БД никаких не увидел.

Comment: Необходимо в целом разобраться с этой CMS. В общем нашёл решение. Зайти через phpmyadmin и редактировать таблицу в БД cms_comments. Там хранятся страницы. А в java я плохо разбираюсь и потому не могу разобрать сложные алгоритмы. Буду делать на php.